# Animate in Nav bar on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, html

Hi I am trying to achieve this nav bar effect: http://kettlenyc.com/ so that when I scroll down the nav bar follows and animates into a fixed position. I have started to code it here, but can't get the animate to work: http://theturning.co.uk/NOAH/

My Jquery looks like this at the moment:

```
$(function() {
var bar = $('#topbar');
var top = bar.css('top');
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        bar.stop().css({'position' : 'absolute'});
    }

    if($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
        bar.stop().animate({'top' : '0px'}, 100).css({'position' : 'fixed'});
    } else {
        bar.stop().animate({'top' : top}, 100);
    }
});
});
```

And CSS:

```
#topbar {
background: url('../images/bg-topbar.png') left top;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
z-index: 999;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Try animating the opacity, set it to 0 first and then animate it to 1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How will this help with changing it from a static position and animating it into a fixed position like the Kettle example?

Answer (score 1):

You should also animate the height and/or the opacity (say, height from `0px` to `50px`, and opacity from `0` to `1`). Also, I would recommend putting the `.css({'position':`fixed`})` before the `.animate`.

```
bar.stop().css({
    'position': 'fixed'
}).animate({
    'top': '0px',
    'height': '50px',
    'opacity': '1'
}, 100);
```

And remember to set (using CSS) the height and opacity both to `0`.
In your script:

```
$(function () {
    var bar = $('#topbar');
    var top = bar.css('top');
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            bar.stop().css({
                'position': 'absolute'
            });
        }

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
            bar.stop().css({
                'position': 'fixed'
            }).animate({
                'top': '0px',
                    'height': '50px',
                    'opacity': '1'
            }, 100);
        } else {
            bar.stop().css({
                'position': 'fixed'
            }).animate({
                'top': top,
                    'height': '0',
                    'opacity': '0'
            }, 100);
        }
    });
});
```

And the CSS would have to include

```
#topbar {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi albertxing, I'm new to jQuery, how could that look in my script?

Comment: See edits above. The height property is optional, if you have any problems with it (i.e. bar not showing before scolling past 600), just delete all the lines to do with height.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hgpd8/4/

You detect the position of the window scroll and if its greater than the position of the header then set the header to fixed. Or just fix it with CSS from the start but that's not as cool.

some added effects but working:

```
if ($("#header").is('*')) {
var elem = $('#header');
var offset = elem.offset();
var leftValue = offset.left;
var topValue =  offset.top + elem.height();
var width = elem.width();
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y >= topValue) {  
 if ($('#header').hasClass('fixed')){    
 }else{
    $('#header').addClass('fixed');
    $('#header').css({
        top: '-60px',
        width:width,
    });
     $('#header').animate({ 
    top: '0',
}, 500, function() {    
        });
}
} else {    
if ($('#header').hasClass('fixed')){        
$('#header').removeClass('fixed');
$('#header').fadeOut('fast', function(){ 
 $('#header').fadeIn('fast');
});
    }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this a little more smoothly like this? https://www.eero.com/details#