# Full Screen Header with Sticky Navigation

Tags: jquery, css, header, navigation, fullscreen

One thing that is definitely trending right now is full screen headers with a sticky navigation all ready in place with the header or that shows upon scrolling past the header. I would like to know the they achieved this on this website...  http://demo.tardigradestudio.com/themes/keylight/ . This is something I would love to incorporate into a site that I am designing. Thanks!

Comment: Please include some code you've produced, showing your attempts to accomplish this.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324702/animate-in-nav-bar-on-scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hgpd8/4/

You detect the position of the window scroll and if its greater than the position of the header then set the header to fixed. Or just fix it with CSS from the start but that's not as cool.

some added effects but working:

```
if ($("#header").is('*')) {
var elem = $('#header');
var offset = elem.offset();
var leftValue = offset.left;
var topValue =  offset.top + elem.height();
var width = elem.width();
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y >= topValue) {  
 if ($('#header').hasClass('fixed')){    
 }else{
    $('#header').addClass('fixed');
    $('#header').css({
        top: '-60px',
        width:width,
    });
     $('#header').animate({ 
    top: '0',
}, 500, function() {    
        });
}
} else {    
if ($('#header').hasClass('fixed')){        
$('#header').removeClass('fixed');
$('#header').fadeOut('fast', function(){ 
 $('#header').fadeIn('fast');
});
    }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is done with a combination of javascript and css. The javascript will set the navigation to `position: fixed;` as soon as it reaches the top of the viewport. Just use your browsers inspector and watch and learn...

You realy need to come up with some code of your own, and tell us exactly where you are stuck if you want a *real* answer. Or perhaps Googling for a tutorial would be a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS. There are so many links that will help you to do that.

**I recommend reading this:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/06/on-scroll-animated-header/**

one of the best tutorial on what you want to achieve. 
The demo is here:
http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/AnimatedHeader/

If you want further explanation, here are few other links:
 Here are few:

[Fixed header in CSS for conditional scroll down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550397/fixed-header-in-css-for-conditional-scroll-down)

http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/