# fullpage.js - add css class to header when scrolling inside a section

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/

on a frontpage of a website and it´s working fine so far.

I have 4 Sections.
The first section has more content than the height of the browser window, so there is the need to scroll inside that section.
I have added the scrollbar and it works with the scrollbar and by using the mousewheel.

Now my problem.
I have a sticky header which I want to reduce in height as soon as there is any scrolling down inside this section (and increase in height as soon as I scroll back up to the top).
So I would like to add the css class "sticky" to the "header" when using the scrollbar of the fullpage.js or the mousewheel so that I can format the header with the class "sticky" differently with css.

Unfortunately the "scroll-Events" doesn´t work here, as already mentioned here:
[FullPage.JS Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139309/fullpage-js-scrolling?s=1|2.9741)

I tried the following

```
$(function(){
window.addEventListener("wheel", function() {
$(document).ready(function(){
var  scrollclass = $('.slimScrollBar').position();
if(scrollclass.top > 0){
$('header').addClass('sticky');
}
else{
$('header').removeClass('sticky');
}
});
});})
```

This kind of works, however the sticky class is not added by the first use of the mousewheel (it´s added by the "second turn of the mousewheel") and is not beeing removed when scrolling back to the top, I need to turn the wheel an additional time after scrolling back to the top to have the sticky class removed again.

If I change the if-statement to >= 0 it works on the first turn of the mousewheel but then I don´t get the class removed when scrolling back to the top.

The second issue is, that this only works by using the mousewheel of course, and not by dragging the scrollbar created by fullpage.js

Any ideas or hints how to solve this?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

you could use the "afterLoad" method, as noted in fullPage.JS's documentation: 
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index